# SVG duplicate ids on one page

Tags: svg

I have images I'm trying to blur across different browsers. The best way I've found is using SVG. I have multiple of these SVGs on one page.

How do I treat the id, since ids should be unique on a page.

```
<svg>
<filter id="blur"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="9" /></filter>
<image xlink:href="/img.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" filter="url(#blur)" />
</svg>

<svg>
<filter id="blur"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="9" /></filter>
<image xlink:href="/img2.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" filter="url(#blur)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the filters are all identical, then you only need one on the page.  You can remove the duplicate filters from all but one SVG.  Or you can move the filter to a separate `<svg>` that can be referenced by all the others.

The main way that duplicate `id` attributes will break SVGs is that it is browser dependent which one gets referenced.  However, that also means that, if all your filters are identical, then that problem won't affect you. Because it won't matter which filter is chosen by any particular broswer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an SVG injector the IDs will be made unique by during the injection. [SVGInject](https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject) adds a random suffix to each referenced ID during injection to avoid ID conflicts. For example `filter1` may become `filter1--inject-Ed83kO72`.